# Proving $(\sin\theta+\operatorname{cosec}\theta)^2+(\cos\theta+\sec\theta)^2\ge9$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that $(\sin\theta+\operatorname{cosec}\theta)^2+(\cos\theta+\sec\theta)^2\ge9$

My approach:

We know that the signs of $\operatorname{sin}\theta$ and $\operatorname{cosec}\theta$ will be same and so of $\operatorname{cos}\theta$ and $\operatorname{sec}\theta$. So we can apply the $AM\ge GM$ inequality. So according to this
$$(\operatorname{sin}\theta+\operatorname{cosec}\theta)\ge2\:\: \text{or}\:\: (\operatorname{sin}\theta+\operatorname{cosec}\theta)\le-2$$ and $$(\operatorname{cos}\theta+\operatorname{sec}\theta)\ge2\;\:\text{or}\:\:(\operatorname{cos}\theta+\operatorname{sec}\theta)\le-2$$
or their squares are $\ge4$ So adding $4+4$ get the answer $8$. But this does not comply with the expected answer.

Now the second method:
Opening the brackets we get $$\operatorname{sin}^2\theta+\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta+\operatorname{cos}^2\theta+\operatorname{sec}^2\theta+2+2=$$ $$7+\operatorname{tan}^2\theta+\operatorname{cot}^2\theta=$$ $$7+(\operatorname{tan}\theta-\operatorname{cot}\theta)^2+2$$ The minimum value will be achieved when the square is $0$. Hence the minimum value is $9$.

What was wrong in the first method$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if sine and cosecant are both -1?

Comment: @BarryCarter even then the square of their sum is $4$

Comment: @BarryCarter [Well-spotted](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28sin+x%2Bcosec+x%29%5E2%2B%28cos+x%2Bsec+x%29%5E2-9+from+0+to+2*pi&dataset=). Then the LHS is undefined, but the divergence on either side is to $\pm\infty$, a bit like $x^{-2}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: The presence of $\sec \theta$ gives an implicit domain such that $\sin \theta \neq \pm 1$.

Comment: The first attempt is a valid proof: it IS true that the formula is always $\geq 8$. It's just not precise enough to show the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing *wrong* with your first method; it's just not powerful enough. You are minimising $(\sin\theta+\operatorname{cosec}\theta)^2$ and $(\cos\theta+\sec\theta)^2$ separately, and adding them. So your result (that the sum is $\ge 8$) is valid. But your method fails to take into account that these minima occur for different values of $\theta$, so they can't both be achieved at once.

So it is not surprising that this method doesn't give the best possible minimum.

---

So see this more clearly, suppose you want to find a minimum value for the expression
$$(x-1)^2+(x+1)^2$$
Using your first method, you could say that $(x-1)^2$ is always $\ge 0$, and $(x+1)^2$ is always $\ge 0$. Therefore their sum is always $\ge 0$.

This is true, but it's obviously not the whole story; these two minima are attained for *different values* of $x$ ($x=1$ and $x=-1$ respectively). And if you rearrange the expression as
$$2x^2+2$$
it is easy to see that it is always $\ge 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Note

\begin{align}
&(\sin\theta+\operatorname{csc}\theta)^2+(\cos\theta+\sec\theta)^2\\
=& \ \sin^2 \theta+\csc^2\theta+\cos^2 \theta+\sec^2\theta+4
= \csc^2\theta+\sec^2\theta+5\\
= &\ \frac1{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta }+5
=\frac4{\sin^22\theta}+5\ge9\\
\end{align}

Comment: You might want to add a line showing that the middle terms from FOILing are two times sin(theta) times csc(theta), etc, making it clearer how you got the 4

Comment: @BarryCarter - done as suggested

Comment: The question was: what is wrong with the first method? You haven't addressed this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like Quanto's answer, but showing more work.

$$(\sin\theta+\csc\theta)^2+(\cos\theta+\sec\theta)^2$$
$$= (\sin\theta + \frac{1}{\sin\theta})^2 + (\cos\theta + \frac{1}{\cos\theta})^2$$
$$=\sin^2\theta + 2 + \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} + \cos^2\theta + 2 + \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$$
$$=4 + \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta + \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta} + \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}$$
$$=4 + (\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) + \frac{\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}$$
$$=5 + \frac{1}{(\cos\theta\sin\theta)^2}$$
$$=5 + \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta))^2}$$
$$=5 + \frac{4}{\sin^2(2\theta)}$$
$$\ge 5 + \frac{4}{\max_{\theta\in[0, \pi]}\sin^2(2\theta)}$$
$$= 5 + 4$$
$$= 9$$

Comment: The question was: what is wrong with the first method? You haven't addressed this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities):
$$
\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)},\quad
\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)},\quad
\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1,\quad
\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x).
$$
Apply as follows (together with standard square of sum formula etc.):
$$
(\sin(x)+\csc(x))^2+(\cos(x)+\sec(x))^2=$$ $$
\left(\sin(x)+\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\right)^2+\left(\cos(x)+\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\right)^2=$$ $$
\sin^2(x)+2+\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}+\cos^2(x)+2+\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=$$ $$
4+(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))+\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\right)=$$ $$
4+1+\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}=$$ $$
5+\frac{1}{(\sin(x)\cos(x))^2}=$$ $$
5+\frac{1}{(\sin(2x)/2)^2}=$$ $$
5+\frac{4}{\sin^2(2x)}=$$ $$
5+4\cdot\frac{1}{\sin^2(2x)}
$$
We have (for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$) the inequalities $-1\leq\sin(\alpha)\leq 1$ that imply $0\leq\sin^2(2x)\leq 1$ and further $\frac{1}{\sin^2(2x)}\geq 1$. Thus, we conclude
$$
(\sin(x)+\csc(x))^2+(\cos(x)+\sec(x))^2=
\ldots=
5+4\cdot\frac{1}{\sin^2(2x)}\geq
5+4\cdot 1=9.
$$

Comment: The question was: what is wrong with the first method? You haven't addressed this at all.